# Magento 2 - Disable Payment Method based on Customer Attribute

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, customer-attribute

I have a custom offline payment method that I want to show based on a customer attribute value.  Eventually I want to check that value against the total and if it is less than the total then disable the method.  But first thing is first, I can't seem to get the customer attribute.  I am testing with group_id which in this case is 1.  This is what I have:

etc > events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_before">
        <observer name="payroll_split_payment_before_save" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\QuoteToOrderObserver" />
    </event>

    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="payroll_payment_method_is_active" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\DisablePayment" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and my Observer:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
  protected $_logger;

  public function __construct(
    // --> delete this line and replace with answer below \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
    // --> delete this line and replace with answer below $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * @param Observer $observer
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    )
  {

    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    if($method_instance == 'payroll')
    { 
      $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($quote->getCustomer()->getId());
      if($customer->getCustomAttribute('group_id')->getValue() == 1)
      {
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in DisablePayment.php

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession` to get current customer group id for logged in customers.

You can use the below code in your `DisablePayment.php` file for the same.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_customerSession;
  protected $_logger;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * @param Observer $observer
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {

    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    if($method_instance == 'payroll')
    { 
        $customerGroupId = $this->getGroupId();
        if($customerGroupId == 1)
        {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        }
    }
  }

  public function getGroupId(){
     if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
            return $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
     endif;
  }
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Hi, thanks for this!  I will test and report back.

I had stated above that I was using group_id as a test.  Eventually I want to use a different customer attribute, it will be a custom one I create called payroll_limit.  It will have a number in it that I will use as a check against the total to show or hide the method.  Will your way still work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check the data coming in $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData(); I've answered as per you question.

Comment: @Summit I will try it and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that the above code works and when I change it to $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData('lastname') for example I can check it against that field.  Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, so I need to show a message that if that user ID (or whatever field) is not acceptable or a match that a message would show in the payment methods place.  Would you know how to show a message if after to check the method wasn't available?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this on the checkout page as I've not do it myself.

Comment: Okay thanks!  Maybe someone else will know how.  I haven't been able to figure it out yet.